# IconButton overflow in container

Tags: flutter

I'm coding a simple Container with red color and a simple icon inside him and all works good.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(170, 0, 0, 0),
      child: Icon(Icons.wifi_lock, color: Colors.lightBlue, size: 150)
  ),
),
```

[Icon with background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIY8t.jpg)

However I if use this with an IconButton then this button overflows the container.

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(170, 0, 0, 0),
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_lock, color: Colors.lightBlue, size: 150),
          onPressed: (){}
      )
  ),
),
```

[IconButton with background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6at.jpg)

I don't understand this behavior and how to fix it. Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are doing is that you are setting the size inside the icon something like this code:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(170, 0, 0, 0),
      child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_lock, color: Colors.lightBlue, size: 150),
          onPressed: (){}
      )
  ),
),
```

So this is increasing the size for the icon but not the button and that's why there is a overflow and the icon is outside the Container.
But if you need to fix it then instead use the following code

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(170, 0, 0, 0),
      child: IconButton(
          iconSize: 150,
          icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_lock, color: Colors.lightBlue,),
          onPressed: (){}
      )
  ),
),
```

remove the `size: 150` parameter inside the icon and instead put `iconSize: 150` parameter inside the button above or below the `icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_lock, color: Colors.lightBlue),` statement. This should fix the issue and you will get the result as you'd like. You don't need to remove the padding as it doesn't affect the overflow outside the container.

Answer (score 0):

`IconButton` has a padding property that you should make it to zero using `EdgeIndests.zero`.

```
Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(170, 0, 0, 0),
        child: IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: Icon(Icons.wifi_lock, color: Colors.lightBlue, size: 150),
            onPressed: (){}
        )
    ),
),
```